Where do i put "簡単" on my sentence?
Im not really good at the sentence structure and my question is, if i want to say "I can speak english easily" do i say "僕は英語簡単を話すできる" or "僕は英語を話すできる簡単", I just want to know if "簡単" is at the end or the middle of this sentence. Any help appreciatted.

Please note that 話すできる is ungrammatical. Use either 話せる (polite: 話せます) or 話すことができる instead.
簡単 is a "な-adjective", so you must append に to use it as an adverb. In your sentence, it can come between the 僕は and 話せる, either before or after the 英語を:

僕は英語を簡単に話せます。
僕は簡単に英語を話せます。


Is "こと" A particle? if it is, How do i use it on my sentence and what are "な-adjective"? Sorry if im asking for too much.

@marcikn what method are you using to learn Japanese? Most resources should explain な adjectives very early on.

@marcikn Don't worry and welcome to the Japanese SE. There are two types of adjectives in Japanese, and な-adjectives are one of them. こと is a broad topic and last time I've tried to explain it to a friend I failed, so it'll probably be best if someone else could answer it to you.

@Leebo I make up random phrases in my mind and then try to translate them to japanese and search ways to do so, and I learned the alphabet on Duolingo.

こと in this context is a nominalizer, which should help with searching here. It provides something for the verb 話す to describe, so that you can then talk about that thing (as a subject for できる). In hyper-literal English, "can do the act of speaking". The key idea here is that できる is a "full" verb, not like the English modal "can"; it functions perfectly well by itself, similar to "can do" in English.
